# How to find out how namespace got polluted?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files, unix

Consider the following little piece of code:

```
// all of these include other headers, lots of code:
#include "myheader1.h"
#include "myheader2.h"
#include <string>

void foo() {
  string s("hello world"); // oh no, why does this compile??
}
```

This compiles, so obviously some of the recursively included header files has a

```
using namespace std;
```

somewhere. How would you go about finding out where that offending line of code is?

Just using `grep` on all header files won't really work because that statement is often used *inside* a function, where it is safe and won't pollute the rest of the code.

Answer (score 6):

grep might be useful anyway. Do a search for "^using namespace". There's a pretty fair chance that inside a function it'll be indented, but outside it won't be...

Answer (score 5):

Compilers usually have the possibility to give the preprocessed output (-E is common) which get also indication of true source line in q `#line` lines.

Comment: Combined with 'grep' or a search in any editor, probably the easiest approach... much easier than opening thousands of files!

Answer (score 3):

Try putting `string s;` after each `#include` statement to find the first place where it doesn't cause the error. This will show you which header is causing the problem. Then do the same with the `#include` statements inside that header, and so on.

A bit of a manual process, but it shouldn't take too long.

Comment: Use binary search algorithm when putting `string s;`. It will take `log(n)` steps.

Comment: Putting one after each `#include` doesn't have the same asymptotic behavior, but is better for small n.  I've done both ways, but the crossover is generally higher for vim than VS 2008.

Comment: N is the total number of lines in header files. It could be very large.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ g++ -E souce.cpp | less
```

From within less type `/using`
and then work backwards from there looking for the previous line that looks like

```
# <file_name> <line_number>
```

That's how the preprocessor tells the compiler what source some code came from so it can do error messages correctly.